# Question regarding hypercube $Q_k$ in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

In the textbook by West, it reads

[image]

It says clearly on the top that edges are pairs of $k$-tuples that differ in exactly one position. It seems that $\{100\}$, and $\{011\}$ differs in all three positions, yet an edge is drawn between these two vertices.

There doesn't seem to be a problem with any other vertices.

In the figure, should there be an edge between vertices $\{100\}$, and $\{011\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in the diagram as we can see there are two $100$.

The $100$ at the top left should be $010$.

With this correction, the definition of the edge should be consistent with the picture.